# Two arguments in one function call

Tags: javascript

I was working on a function practice from the book "A Smarter Way to Learn JavaScript", I do not understand why the answer is as below. Could anybody explain why? Thank you very much!

Question:
Code a function call that has two arguments. The first argument is a variable. The second argument is another function call. The second function call takes the argument 10. The value returned by the first function is assigned to est, which hasn't been declared beforehand.

Answer from the book:
var est = makeEst(empNum, calcBonus(10));

Comment: How do you interpret it?

Comment: What could be explained here? The question is the explanation of the code listed as the answer. Read the documentation of JavaScript [functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions) and [variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you see `someString`(), such as `calcBonus(10)`, that's a function call: someString is the function name, and someOptionalArgs are the arguments that the function is called with. As the book says, the argument to that second function call should be `10`, so that's what goes inside of the parentheses of calcBonus.

Arguments are separated by commas, so as you can see, you call the makeEst function with `empNum` (one argument) followed by a comma, followed by `calcBonus(10)` (another argument).

Then the result of the whole makeEst function call is assigned to `est` with `=`, which is the assignment operator.

Comment: Thank you very much! my original code was "var est = one(10);" because I thought the first argument is the variable, which has been assigned to est, thats why I did not understand why there are two arguments inside. Plus why do we need "makeEst" outside of the two arguments. can we remove "makeEst", keep as "var est = (empNum, calcBonus(10));" ? I feel my question is pretty ...><!!! Thanks again.

Comment: If there's no function name, the interpreter has no idea which function you're trying to call. There is such a thing as anonymous functions and IIFEs, but leave that for later.

Answer (score 0):

so the variable empNumber is basically assigned to the variable est. And the calcBonus(10) is a another function that will be executed. What don’t you understand or what is confusing you?